# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation does not exist during installing external packages using pip

Tags: python, django, package

I have created an django resuable app. It has an model file contain following modle
models.py

```
from django.db import models

class KnApiGatewayToken(models.Model):
    access_token = models.TextField()
    refresh_token = models.TextField()
```

There is 1 migration file

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='KnApiGatewayToken',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('access_token', models.TextField()),
                ('refresh_token', models.TextField()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

The resuable app i.e. the django project is working perfectly. I can see the models in the admin side also.

Now i have installed this package ( django resuable app ) in another django project using following command

```
pip install /path/to/package/dist/package.tar
```

Package get installed successfully, but during runserver, it is giving following error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "kn_python_amazon_ad_api_knapigatewaytoken" does not exist
LINE 1: ...on_ad_api_knapigatewaytoken"."refresh_token" FROM "kn_python...
```

I have tried running `makemigration` and `migrate` command too, but still it gives me the same error.

Comment: when it says relation does not exist, it refers to a connection that is tried to be done via a foreign key where the Id in the other table is not present (related name)